# About Cucumber framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, junit

I am an automation tester, right now i am working in selenium tool ,worked with different frameworks like junit, testng. Now there is need to work on cucumber framework.

I followed the steps in the different sites and finally setup the cucumber framework.

But i have so many doubts, if you guys have time then please answer me.

1. I have the folder structure like below

   ```
   src/test/java/test/Goolesearch/Runtest.java
   src/test/resource/test/test.feature
   ```

   if i change the folder structure for ex: test to test1 (`src/test/resource/test1/test.feature`) it not working. Can you please tell me how cucumber works.
2. I was trying to extend the test class to reuse the methods. But i got an error , is it possible to extend the class or how to do it?
3. How to do the data parameterization.
4. How to have multiple tests / how to execute multiple tests and what is the configuration.
5. Is it possible to implement the grid if so then what it the content in the feature file.

Thanks

Comment: Re #5: What is "the grid"?

Comment: #2 I would not recommend making a test hierarchy. Instead I would recommend making a separate layer that would be called from tests. That layer would be some kind of service, that will use interface of our target application (i.e. GUI or API). Using application interface directly in tests leads to really tight coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Re #1: This can happen when you have two `test.feature` afterwards. You should try `.../test/test1.feature` instead (i.e. rename the feature file, not the folder / package it's in).

Re #2: It's possible to extend the test class. If you gave us the error, then we might be able to help.

Re #3: You usually write a "Data Table" in Gherkin. See the documentation: http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html

Re #4: Just write multiple tests in a feature file. Each feature file has one scenario but can contain several blocks that start with `Given`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron , it is almost a 17 to reply sorry for that.Since i dont have an access in work space.I have few more doubts on your comments i will be asking in a day or two after i works.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Which runner you are using? Cucumber command line runner or cucumber with junit? Can you share run configuration details?

Another alternate for cucumber runner or bdd implementation is [QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) it supports different approaches testng, QAF-BDD, cucumber-gherkin, keyword driven using excel/csv and have different design concepts for web/mobile automation using selenium-webdriver.

You can strat with [blank project](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project) or check [cucumber-gherkin example](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/releases/download/2.1.9-RC2/QAFGherkin.zip) which is working example with configuration for [QAF-gherkin-client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf-gherkin-client.html).

Comment: Yes, i also will suggest QAF. We are using it and found it very easy with lots of web and mobile automation features.